# XSL template - need help getting class name from row

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a test html table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:10px;" />
    <th style="width:80px;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:350px;">Number</th>
    <th style="width:80px;">Date<br />2014-12-31</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent" data-level="0">
    <td />
    <td class="Center">123-12345</td>
    <td>     Range</td>
    <td class="Number">
      <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child" >
    <td>
      <div class="childNo"  />
    </td>
    <td class="Center">D</td>
    <td>     Test Description</td>
    <td class="Number">123456<br /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

All I want to do is check to see if the `<TR>` class is "parent", if so, concatenate "expando" to the class.  So it will look like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:10px;" />
    <th style="width:80px;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:350px;">Number</th>
    <th style="width:80px;">Date<br />2014-12-31</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent expando" data-level="0">
   ....
```

I can't seem to do this with xsl.  I'm not sure if I need to use a template-match.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the whole table and only add the class to all `tr` having `class="parent"` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tr[@class='parent']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'parent expando'"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="data-level" select="@data-level"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="td"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:10px;"></th>
    <th style="width:80px;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:350px;">Number</th>
    <th style="width:80px;">Date<br>2014-12-31
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent expando" data-level="0">
    <td></td>
    <td class="Center">123-12345</td>
    <td>     Range</td>
    <td class="Number"><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <div class="childNo"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="Center">D</td>
    <td>     Test Description</td>
    <td class="Number">123456<br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The template with the match pattern `<xsl:template match="tr[@class='parent']">`
matches all `tr` that have the class `parent`, using

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'parent expando'"/>
   <xsl:attribute name="data-level" select="@data-level"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="td"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

copies the whole `tr` and changes the value of the attribute `class` to both classes.

**Update:** As additional requirement, this should also work for `tr` that could have additional classes together with the class `parent`.
Following adjustment handles this:

```
<xsl:template match="tr[contains(@class,'parent')]">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="class" select="concat(@class, ' expando')"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="data-level" select="@data-level"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="td"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now all `tr` will be matched that contain the class `parent`, and as new value for the  class attribute the class `expando` will be added to the current class value:

```
<xsl:attribute name="class" select="concat(@class, ' expando')"/>
```

**Update:** As noticed as comment, this is no valid XSLT 1.0 syntax for `<xsl:attribute>` - it should be

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@class, ' expando')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="data-level">
  <xsl:value-of select="@data-level"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

This was tested with an online XSLT processor which didn't throw any error though the XSLT was previously declared as 1.0. As mentioned in the comments, it was just my mistake to use an XSLT 2.0 processor (Saxon 9.5.1.6) that, in the online version, does not pass all errors and warnings  to the user. Switching to an XSLT 1.0 processor (Saxon 6.5) resulted in the proper error `Attribute select is not allowed on this element`.

Though this is the accepted answer, in my opinion the answer given by Lingamurthy CS is the better/cleaner approach as it only changes the necessary `class` attribute. I should have known better to save some unnecessary `xsl:copy`.

Comment: Thanks Matthias!  I've tried the code but it is not working for me.  Do I insert the above two template matches after  <xsl:template match"/">....</xsl:template>

Comment: @EriqaBana That's only an example for an XSLT matching the whole table, I've saved it here: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpY  As I don't know your full XSLT, it's not easy to guess why it's not working. Could you add your XSLT to your question?

Comment: Mattias, I figured out why it wasn't working. Some of my <TR> will have more than one class specified in addition to "parent".  Yes, the code you have will work if I have just "parent" class specified but will fail if I have more than one specified.  I tried "contains" but not getting the right result either.

Comment: @EriqaBana No problem, I've just adjusted it with contains here: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpY/2  and will also update this in my answer.

Comment: Once again, you have a mismatch between the declared version 1.0 and the syntax of <xsl:attribute> which can only work in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for mentioning again, I shouldn't trust xsltransform.net as it won't throw any error for this.

Comment: + 1. Well, it's not really an error to process an 1.0 stylesheet with a 2.0 processor. Just remember to select Saxon 6.5 from the menu.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, and it should (even if processing a 1.0 stylesheet with a 2.0 processor @MathiasMüller). But if you select an XSLT 1.0 processor (Saxon 6.5 or Xalan), you will see that no result is returned.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know, I am saying it is not obliged to throw an error because "XSLT 2.0 processors are not required to implement backward-compatibility mode." - That's my understanding of Michael Kay's quote at least.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thank you, that's the explanation I needed. I thought it to be possible to process both, based on the version declared in the XSLT. And thanks to michael.hor257k for the info how I can test 1.0 for more reliable results. I only tested with Saxon 9.5.1.6.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I meant something else altogether: xsltransform.net  does not pass all error messages and warnings to the user. Saxon 9 does warn when running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet. And Xalan-J throws an error when detecting a "select" attribute on <xsl:attribute> element (and so should Saxon 6.5, IMHO).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ah, I see - I misunderstood your comment. Apologies.

Comment: @MathiasMüller None required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following stylesheet, which has two templates. First, an identity template to copy all the nodes as they are in source document. Second, to update only the `@class` whose parent is `tr` and value if "parent", hence, no need to worry about `tr` element or its other attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output 
        method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tr/@class[contains(., 'parent')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' expando')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: That's the better approach. Only one minor detail: you should adjust to `<xsl:template match="@class[contains(., 'parent') and parent::tr]">` as OP wants to match not only `tr` that only have the class parent, but also `tr` with additional classes which he only mentioned as comment below my answer and didn't update in his question.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, definitely. That would be more readable. Let me edit my answer. Thanks.